# How to write the “to the power” and some text like as shown in Android?

Tags: android

[How to do in android which i given in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CYPV.png)

[I am tried from this code but not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2GgP.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this code, you need to use Spanned to keep changes

```
 TextView txt =findViewById(R.id.txt);

    Spanned str ;
    String myStr ="This is test";

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
       str =(Html.fromHtml("X<sup><small>123</small></sup>"+myStr, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
    } else {
       str =(Html.fromHtml("X<sup><small>123</small></sup>"+myStr));

    }

    txt.setText(str);
```

[image]